# read a file using scanner and save it in string including white space

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a text file that i want to read. I have no problem doing that. 
My problem is that i need to check if a line has a white space or not. 
for example, lets assume the below is my text file. I want to save "something" in new string and if it has nothing in that column and row then i want to " " as string. 
    Column1     Column2 Column3
Row1    Something   Something   Something
Row2        Something   Something
Row3            Something

i tried to read the file with scanner and and save each line in new string. but i have no clue to how to get the white space from the string. i'm not sure if this method will work or not.

any suggestions

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for white space just use

```
String out;
if(inputLine.indexOf(" ")!=-1){
  // Whitespace exists in string
  out = "something";
} else {
  // No whitespace exists
  out = " ";
}
```